# How to get Google (Play) Services on Huawei phones bought in China?

Tags: google-play-store, huawei, google-play-services

I have bought a Huawei Nova 3e (aka Huawei P20 Lite) from China but it does not include Google Play Store / Gmail and other Google services.

I have tried several things

- Installing and running "Google Installer" (version 1 and 2.0)
- Installation Google Framework, Google Play Services, etc. in different orders (as seen on different websites), either by copying from a phone with a working Google Play Store or from [apps.evozi.com](https://apps.evozi.com/apk-downloader/)

Previously, I was using some Xiaomi and I had to install a Global ROM which included Google stuff.

Shall I also install a new ROM on my Huawei phone?

Or shall I root it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spent 3 days struggling to solve the issue.

The trick has been suggested by a friend who is working in the phone industry in China as developer: you need to install **Core GMS Packages**.

There is an app which helps to install the GMS (*gmsinstaller.apk*): running it will download what you need and install it during a reboot phase.

I have found the information, as well as a link for the app, here: https://www.skmlifestyle.com/destinations/china/living-in-suzhou-jiangsu-china/core-gms-package-for-huawei-android-phones-google-play-services-apk-download/

There might other ways to download this app somewhere on the web.

Cheers